# Proper Way to Handle Vector of Pointers to Derived Classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, memory-management, std

I don't know how to properly have a vector of derived classes without memory leaks. I tried the following, but it has problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct base {};

struct derived : public base
{
  derived() {}
};

struct Layer
{
  vector<base*> effects;

  Layer() {}

  ~Layer()
  {
    for(int ii = 0; ii < effects.size(); ii++)
    {
      cout << "called effect deleter" << endl;
      delete effects[ii];
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  vector<Layer> layers;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    layers.push_back(Layer());
    layers[i].effects.push_back(new derived());
    cout << i << endl;
  }
}
```

When I compile and run this code, I get the following output:

```
0
called effect deleter
1
called effect deleter
called effect deleter
```

I'm confused. Why does it only print 0 and 1 instead of 0 through 9? If I remove the Layer destructor, won't I have a memory leak? What is the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: `Layer` is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), so it can cause problems when `layers` grows its capacity and has to make copies of existing `Layer` instances

Answer (score 1):

If `base *b`, but `*b` is actually a `derived`, then `delete b;` is instant UB, because `base::~base()` is not `virtual`. Essentially, you try to delete the `base` part of `*b` (directed by the type of `*b`, which is `base`), but, because the destructor isn't virtual, you forget to destroy the `derived` part first. This leads to horrible things happening (probably some kind of stack corruption?). Fix it:

```
struct base {
    virtual ~base() = default;
};
```

Also, `Layer::Layer(Layer const&)` (the implicitly-defined copy constructor) is broken, since it duplicates the `base*` pointers from the argument. This copy constructor is called when `std::vector<Layer>` needs to resize its storage, which entails allocating a new hunk of contiguous memory and move-constructing new `Layer`s out of the old ones, then destroying the old ones. Except a) `Layer` doesn't have a move constructor (the user-declared destructor prevents its generation), so "moving" `Layer`s just copies them, and b) copying `Layer`s is conceptually flawed, since when one `Layer` is destroyed it will `delete` all of its `base`s, and then the other `Layer` will try to delete them again later. Disable `Layer` copying and write its move.

```
struct Layer {
    std::vector<base*> effects;
    Layer() = default;
    Layer(Layer const&) = delete;
    Layer(Layer&&) = default;
    Layer &operator=(Layer const&) = delete;
    Layer &operator=(Layer &&other) {
        std::swap(this->effects, other.effects);
        // what used to be this->effects will be deleted when other is destroyed
        return *this;
    }

    ~Layer() {
        for(int ii = 0; ii < effects.size(); ii++) {
            std::cout << "called effect deleter\n"; // endl is usually unnecessary, and "\n" is portable
            delete effects[ii];
        }
    }
};
```

The moral is: use smart pointers :).

```
struct effect_deleter {
    void operator()(base *b) {
        std::cout << "called effect deleter\n";
        delete b;
    }
};
struct Layer {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base, effect_deleter>> effects;
    // 3 constructors, 2 operator=s, and 1 destructor
    // all doing the right thing, "for free"
    // "Rule of 5" becomes "Rule of 0"
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Layer> layers;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        layers.emplace_back(); // using push_back(Layer()) constructs a temporary Layer, then constructs the actual Layer in the vector by moving from the temporary; emplace_back just passes the arguments (here nothing) on to the constructor of Layer
        layers[i].effects.emplace_back(new derived()); // similar
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as a straight vector in c++ - different derived classes have different sizes, and as such, you get slicing when the copy constructors place elements in the array (classic object slicing).

The least painful way of doing this properly is by using a vector of `shared_ptr`'s to the base class. It is possible to use an array of `unique_ptr`'s too, but you have to be *very* careful with that, since things like range-based for-loops can move the ownership of your data into the temporary iteration variable.

Comment: Ok, but the OP knows that and is using vectors of pointers. Slicing is not what's happening. There are other things going wrong here.

Comment: Declare the destructor virtual

Comment: @jscmerge That's one thing. This question is a kaleidoscope of brokenness, though. That doesn't fix everything.